# Error trying to compile a C++ program that uses a shared library

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile an example program that uses a shared library (also developed by me) in C++, which name is `libtestlib.so`.

## The error

I have compiled the shared library without problems, but when I try to compile an executable that uses this library, I have the following error: `iface/libtestlib.so: undefined reference to 'ALIB::function()'`

## What I have done

I have done the following:

C++ library (files in `$project_dir/lib1`):

```
// HEADER
#ifndef ALIB_H
#define ALIB_H

namespace ALIB{
    int function();
}

#endif
-------------------------------------------
// SOURCE
#include "alib.h"

using namespace ALIB;

int ALIB::function(){
    return 101;
}
```

The C interface for the C++ library (files in `$project_dir/iface`)

```
// HEADER
#ifndef IFACE_H
#define IFACE_H

#include "alib.h"

extern "C"{
    int IFACE_function();
}

#endif
--------------------------------
// SOURCE
#include "iface.h"

int IFACE_function(){
    return ALIB::function();
}
--------------------------------------------------------
// CMakeLists used to build the library:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT( testlib )
include_directories( ../lib1 )
add_library( testlib SHARED iface.cpp )
```

The executable that uses the library (files in `$project_dir/main`):

```
// SOURCE
#include "iface.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << IFACE_function() << endl;
}

-------------------------------------

// CMakeLists used to build the executable (file in `$project_dir`):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT( testlib )
find_library( LIB NAMES testlib PATHS ./iface )
include_directories( ./lib1 ./iface )
add_executable( testlib ./main/main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( testlib ${LIB} )
```

## Generated files

`$project_dir`:
all generated by cmake. (CmakeLists.txt, CMakeCache, cmake_install.cmake, MakeFile)

`$project_dir/lib1`:
`alib.cpp` and `alib.h`

`$project_dir/iface`:
`iface.cpp, iface.h, libtestlib.so` and all generated by cmake.

`$project_dir/main`:
`main.cpp`.

As tree:

```
$project_dir
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── ...
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt~
├── iface
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt~
│   ├── iface.cpp
│   ├── iface.h
│   ├── libtestlib.so
│   └── Makefile
├── lib1
│   ├── alib.cpp
│   └── alib.h
├── main
│   └── main.cpp
└── Makefile
```

Comment: It's a linker issue, not a compiler error. Can you see the o files generated?

Comment: None of the code shown is C, so why would you use a C-interface?

Comment: alib.cpp should be compiled and linked.

Comment: I use a C interface because the real library that I have to use is bigger and written in C++. This is only an example.

Comment: Is there a CMakeLists file for lib1? Building of libtestlib.so should either links with library generated from lib1, or includes sources from lib1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yuan's comment I have found the problem. I needed to add the `alib.cpp` file to the `CMakeLists.txt`, this way:

```
// CMakeLists used to build the library:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT( testlib )
include_directories( ../lib1 )
add_library( testlib SHARED iface.cpp ../lib1/alib.cpp )
```